# Persisting values in Flutter's Flip Widget across rebuilds

Tags: flutter, widget, rebuild

i have three variable  `var cPrayerTime;  var remingTime;  var cPrayerName;` values for those variables set by a async function and I am using this variables into flip widget when widget fliped it is actually rebuild and when this widget rebuild at start those variables are empty so I need that 1 st flip values in 2nd flip

Comment: can you show a code?

Comment: codeshare.io/K8R7VN this is my fully working code

Comment: I review your code. You can try one thing.
=> Define these three variables `var cPrayerTime;  var remingTime;  var cPrayerName;` outside the `SalahTimeRemingWidget` class like below the all imports.